# Google Sheets Script .flush() question/dream?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

From inside a macro in script, I am working with a very large multi-tab Google Sheets Sheet. Does anyone know how to .flush() a particular tab of the Sheet? The .flush command is taking a long time to process and since I am placing numbers (not formulas) on the tab that are not inter-related to any other cells, not sure what .flush() is doing.

Comment: In short, this is not possible. Flush is a spreadsheet method, by definition it applies to the entire spreadsheet.

Comment: Hey! Just like @Sergeinsas has mentioned, the `flush` method is specific to the entire Spreadsheet. Is the use of `flush` required in your case?

Comment: The function ends but the sheets does not finish what it is doing (whatever that is) for 25 seconds. The overhead of Google sheets seems massive.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your code and a sensitive copy of your sheet as well? Also, do you have lots of data in the Spreadsheet?